# OOP programming in octave

Tags: matlab, oop, octave

I am trying to run an OOP program in octave originally written for Matlab. I am not able to get most of the part right but not able to call methods.

Here's the sample code.

```
obj = Motor('SamplePeriod', 1/256, 'Beta');
methods(obj)
Methods for class Motor:

Motor  Update

obj.Update();
error: invalid index for class
```

I tried reading the manual, couldn't get the instruction. Also there aren't any samples online as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Calling-a-method-of-an-object-td4645430.html), you need to use the alternate way to call your method:

```
m = motor(...) 
p = power(m, ...)
```

In your case that would be

```
Update(obj)
```

As mentioned by @Daniel

Comment: I think he'll probably need `obj = Update (obj)`

Answer (score 0):

You can still call a method of a class using `obj.Update()` syntax, but you need to implement a special method in your class:

```
function varargout = subsref (obj, idx)
  persistent __method__ method4field typeNotImplemented
  if isempty(__method__)

    __method__ = struct();
    __method__.Update = @(o,varargin) Update (o, varargin{:});

  # Error strings
    method4field = "Class #s has no field #s. Use #s() for the method.";
    typeNotImplemented = "#s no implemented for class #s.";

  end

  method = idx(1).subs;
  if ~isfield(__method__, method)
    error('Unknown method #s.',method);
  else
    fhandle = __method__.(method);
  end
  if strcmp (idx(2).type, '()')

    args = idx(2).subs;
    if isempty(args)
     out = fhandle (obj);
    else
      out = fhandle (obj, args{:});
    end

    varargout{1} = out;

  end
endfunction
```

More details can be found inside [geometry](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/octave/geometry-2.1.1.tar.gz?download) package, look into `inst/io/@svg` folder.